# flask + ngrok - redirect doesn't work

Tags: python, http, flask, ngrok

I've got the following app:

server.py

```
@app.route('/')
    def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login')
    def login():
    return 'hey'
```

index.html

```
<body>
 <form action="http://localhost:5000/login" , method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
```

Now I run ngrok:

```
ngrok http 5000
```

After typing address (generated by ngrok) into web browser I can see index.html page with button, but when I press the button it redirects me to http://localhost:5000/login where I can see: "connection refused".
My question is how to set ngrok and flask server the way they can communicate?

P.S. I've put only a part of my code just for better reading

Comment: Even simpler, use `pyngrok` (`pip install pyngrok`) to invoke and manage `ngrok` right from within your `server.py`. [Here's a full Flask example](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), but basically you'd just need to `from pyngrok import ngrok` and then `ngrok.connect(5000)` when you're defining the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you add the `POST` method to the login route

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    return 'hey'
```

and change the form action to

```
<body>
 <form action="/login", method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
```

hm?

Comment: I forgot to write 'POST' here, but it does exist in my code, I'll fix it now. Btw I tried with: action="/login" and it works :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Btw, I've figured out how to make it other way. After running command:

```
ngrok http 5000
```

I get ngrok address thanks to this python script:

```
import json
import os

def get_ngrok_address():
    os.system("curl  http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels > tunnels.json")

    with open('tunnels.json') as data_file:
        datajson = json.load(data_file)

return dict(zip(['http', 'https'], [i['public_url'] for i in datajson['tunnels']]))
```

It just gets json object and converts it to python dict:

```
'http' -> ngrok_http_address
'https' -> ngrok_https_address
```

Before server start I pass generated address to all html templates e.x.:

```
<body>
  <form action="{{ ngrok_address }}/login", method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your host of application.

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and then run the command `ngrok http 5000`

also add `POST` method for the your route.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
 return 'hey'
```

Comment: I forgot to type here 'POST' in my route args, but it exists in my code. Your solution works fine as well. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! and please mark the answer as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Flask-PyNgrok](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-PyNgrok/) to use ngrok as flask application extension.